# Brute-force Prolog SAT solver for boolean formulas

Tags: prolog, sat, clpb

I'm trying to write an algorithm that naively looks for models of a boolean formula (NNF, but not CNF).

The code I have can check an existing model, but it'll fail (or not finish) when asked to find models, seemingly because it generates infinitely many solutions for `member(X, Y)` along the lines of `[X|_], [_,X|_], [_,_,X|_]...`

What I have so far is this:

```
:- op(100, fy, ~).    
:- op(200, xfx, /\).  
:- op(200, xfx, \/).  
:- op(300, xfx, =>).  
:- op(300, xfx, <=>). 

formula(X) :- atom(X).
formula(~X) :- formula(X).
formula(X /\ Y) :- formula(X), formula(Y).
formula(X \/ Y) :- formula(X), formula(Y).
formula(X => Y) :- formula(X), formula(Y).
formula(X <=> Y) :- formula(X), formula(Y).

model(1, _).
model(X, F) :- atom(X), member([X, 1], F).
model(~X, F) :- atom(X), member([X, 0], F). % NNF
model(A /\ B, F) :- model(A, F), model(B, F).
model(A \/ B, F) :- (model(A, F); model(B, F)).
model(A => B, F) :- model(~A \/ B, F).
model(A <=> B, F) :- model((A => B) /\ (B => A), F).

sat(A) :- model(A, F), \+ (member([X, 1], F), member([X, 0], F)).


%%% examples:
% formula(~(~ (a /\ b) \/ (c => d))).
% model(a, [[a,1]]).
```

Is there a better data structure for `F`, or some other way the partially-instantiated lists can be cut off?

Edit: Added definitions and examples.

Comment: Please make your code self-contained, so that others can actually try it.

Comment: Sorry, I edited in the rest of the code.

Comment: One comment about the representation: You know that each such list has exactly 2 elements. In such cases, it is better to use terms like `x=0`, `x=1` to represent the bindings more compactly: `[x,0]` is `.(x, .(0, [])`, wasting space for one additional functor `./2` and one atom `[]` for each such structure. In contrast, `x=0` is `=(x,0)`, i.e., just one functor and its two arguments. As others have said though, you can actually delegate the binding to Prolog easily by using actual logical variables instead. You can store a symbol/variable correspondence instead of a variable/value one!

Answer (score 3):

**Use [clpb](/questions/tagged/clpb)!**

```
:- use_module(library(clpb)).
```

Sample query using [`sat/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sat/1):

```
?- sat(~(~ (A * B) + (C * D))).
A = B, B = 1, sat(1#C*D).
```

Some variables (`A` and `B`) *already* have been bound to exactly one Boolean value (in above query), but search is not yet complete (which is indicated by residual goals).

To trigger the smart brute-force enumeration of all solutions use [`labeling/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=labeling/1) like so:

```
?- sat(~(~ (A * B) + (C * D))), labeling([A,B,C,D]).
   A = B, B = 1, C = D, D = 0
;  A = B, B = D, D = 1, C = 0
;  A = B, B = C, C = 1, D = 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by writing a `generate_model` predicate that created a pre-defined list with exactly one element for each variable:

```
generate_model([], []).
generate_model([X|T], [[X,_]|T2]) :- generate_model(T, T2).

sat(A) :- 
  var_list(A, Vars),
  generate_model(Vars, F),
  model(A, F).
```

Comment: I feel like `generate_model/2` resembles [`term_variables/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_variables/2) a lot, am I missing something?

Comment: @DanielLyons. I concur. It does. `term_variables/2` plus some suitable `maplist/3`... Directly using logical variables would be more idiomatic (and quite likely a lot faster). Also, it would safeguard against using `F` like `[[x,0],[x,1],...]` (which is bad!)

Comment: Oooh, that's neat! Though in this specific case the formula itself doesn't contain real Prolog variables - each "variable" is represented by an atomic term (usually a string). My `var_list` predicate then lists unique atoms the same way that `term_variables` lists variables.

Comment: And yeah, I guess logical variables would be better in this case - but most of the stuff we're doing is symbol manipulation and not evaluation. I needed this to automatically check equisatisfiability to verify the correctness of some Tseytin implementations.

Comment: If your semantics are similar enough to Prolog's, you could allow it to do the lifting for you though. :)

Answer (score -1):

Do I understand you, that you are happy with a single model. You
don't need labeling or sat_count. Here is an alternative [model finder](https://gist.github.com/jburse/99d9a636fd6218bac8c380c093e06287#file-classical-p-L62), that is similar to yours, but will only return consistent models.

Since it finds counter models, you need to supply the negation of the formula to find a model. The predicate maze/3 was developed as a negative implementation of the positive predicate proof/2:

```
% Find a counter model.
% maze(+Norm,+List,-List)
maze(or(A,_),L,_) :- member(A,L), !, fail.
maze(or(A,B),L,R) :- !, inv(A,C), maze(B,[C|L],R).
maze(and(A,_),L,R) :- maze(A,L,R), !.
maze(and(_,B),L,R) :- !, maze(B,L,R).
maze(A,L,_) :- member(A,L), !, fail.
maze(A,L,M) :- oneof(L,B,R), connective(B), !, 
                 inv(A,C), inv(B,D), maze(D,[C|R],M).
maze(A,L,[B|L]) :- inv(A,B).
```

It can find counter models to all of the following fallacies:

```
Affirming a Disjunct: (p v q) & p => ~q.
Affirming the Consequent: (p => q) & q => p.
Commutation of Conditionals: (p => q) => (q => p).
Denying a Conjunct: ~(p & q) & ~p => q.
Denying the Antecedent: (p => q) & ~p => ~q.
Improper Transposition: (p => q) => (~p => ~q).
```

Here is an example run:

```
Jekejeke Prolog 2, Runtime Library 1.2.5
(c) 1985-2017, XLOG Technologies GmbH, Switzerland

?- negcase(_,N,F), norm(F,G), maze(G,[],L), 
   write(N), write(': '), sort(L,R), write(R), nl, fail; true.
Affirming a Disjunct: [pos(p),pos(q)]
Affirming the Consequent: [neg(p),pos(q)]
Commutation of Conditionals: [neg(p),pos(q)]
Denying a Conjunct: [neg(p),neg(q)]
Denying the Antecedent: [neg(p),pos(q)]
Improper Transposition: [neg(p),pos(q)]
```

Interestingly the thing is much faster than CLP(B). Here are some timings running the same problem in CLP(B) and with maze:

```
?- time((between(1,1000,_), negcaseclp(_,N,F,L),
   sat(~F), once(labeling(L)), fail; true)).
% Up 296 ms, GC 3 ms, Thread Cpu 250 ms (Current 01/27/18 00:34:20)
Yes 
?- time((between(1,1000,_), negcase(_,_,F),
   norm(F,G), maze(G,[],_), fail; true)).
% Up 82 ms, GC 0 ms, Thread Cpu 78 ms (Current 01/27/18 00:30:21)
Yes
```